# Is there a way to see the library function code in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm interested in how List.combine is done

```
val combine : 'a list -> 'b list -> ('a * 'b) list

Transform a pair of lists into a list of pairs: combine [a1; ...; an] [b1; ...; bn] is [(a1,b1); ...; (an,bn)].
```

Comment: Hmm, SML Basis Library doesn't have `List.combine`. What you paste here is [documentation of `List.combine`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) in OCaml. What do you want to ask?

Comment: SML has `ListPair.zip`, which has type `'a list * 'b list -> ('a * 'b) list`. So I don't know where your function is coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which implementation of SML? [MosML](https://github.com/kfl/mosml), [MLton](http://mlton.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mlton/) and [SML/NJ](http://smlnj-gforge.cs.uchicago.edu/scm/viewvc.php/?root=smlnj) are all open source, so you should be able to just download the source code or look at it in your browser. Actually, the MosML implementation of ListPair is [here](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/Rel-2.10/src/mosmllib/ListPair.sml), with zip right at the top, assuming that that's the function you were talking about. It certainly does exactly what you described.

Comment: It might be that the MosML repository is a bit easier to navigate in this case, but here is the SML/NJ implementation of [ListPair](http://smlnj-gforge.cs.uchicago.edu/scm/viewvc.php/sml/trunk/system/Basis/Implementation/list-pair.sml?view=markup&root=smlnj).